# bootstrap datepicker not completely visible in browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hello I have used bootstrap datepicker in my project. But it goes out of screen. Means I am not able to change the month. How to fix this. Here is the screenshot :
 [image]

**Project Description** : In my project, I have made an admin panel who can see all the fields and can edit` the fields. So he can change a date also. When he will click on that date, a new calendar will open.

**Problem** :  But the problem is for the first row calendar is not completely visible so admin is not able to change the month or year. I am using X-editable tool for all these implementation.

**What I have tried** : I have tried zoom in and out but still it is out from window. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom css to the datepicker class
either using
"datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" these classes from bootstrap or using your class. You can add one class to datepicker using jquery.

$('#dateinput').datepicker({
    autoclose: true 
}).addClass("customClass");

As per requirement, you can apply to all or only to first and last.